# How do I view the template of a form in Elementor even if I'm logged in?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, elementor

I'm building a signup plugin for my wordpress site, everything is working fine. However, when I insert the shortcode into an Elementor page it obviously shows me the message: "You are already signed in."

If I log out I see the form of course, and that's it.

What I want to do is display the form while editing the Elementor page so that I can see any changes, the point is that I'm new and I don't know what conditions to use in the if else branch to do this.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
function render_signup_form(){
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      return __( 'You are already signed in.' );
   } else { 
      $template = require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/signup-form.php' );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research and several attempts I was able to get this to work with the code below, however I'm not sure if that's the correct practice. If this is bad practice or if there are better methods of doing this I hope someone corrects it.

```
function render_signup_form(){
   if ( \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->editor->is_edit_mode() ) {
      $template = require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/signup-form.php' );
   } else if ( is_user_logged_in() )  {
      return __( 'You are already signed in.' );
   } else {
      // Altrimenti, usa il percorso del template originale
      $template = require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/signup-form.php' );
   } 
}
```